# Detect device/app on Rest call

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, unity-game-engine, request

I have a rails project whose API's are used by two different but related apps.
One app (Parent) is made using Unity, while other one (Child) is with native (iOS & Android).

In case of error response.

Unity app requires 2xx series status code,in case of any other status code they read it as success case.

While native (iOS & Android) apps need 4xx series status code, in case of any other status code they read it as success case.

Is there any way that from request I can know that which app sent request?

or any other solution to handle this?

Comment: you dont use ` User-Agent ` header?

Comment: You can see this  gem https://github.com/podigee/device_detector. This may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way that from request I can know that which app sent
>   request?

Yes. Several ways.

**1**.Use form to send which device is making the request then access this fro your rail server.

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();


//From Unity
form.AddField("App", "Unity");
```

Or

```
//From Native
form.AddField("App", "Native");
```

Then send:

```
UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
```

**2**.Use a custom header to send which device is making the request then access this from your rail server.

```
//From Unity
UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader("App", "Unity");
```

Or

```
//From Native
UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader("App", "Native");
```

All you need to do is access "App" on rail for both of these.

**3**.Use json or xml to store which device the request is coming from the access this from the server.

The API used here is for Unity but you can do similar thing on iOS and Android too for the native app with Object-C and Java API. It's still the-same thing.

Comment: So in all cases, app has to send something in headers or so ?

Comment: Yes, the app will have to identify itself some how with one those ways. That's not automatically done.

Answer (score 0):

request method has parameter as

```
request.user_agent
```

Comment: its gives me "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
How its going to tell me app?

Comment: This can tell me device but not app